# Getting all children of object as a collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a entity framework object Zoo that has a property called Animals.
Once I get a collection of Zoo's (List) I would then like to get a collection of all the animals in this list

I have tried

```
var animals = zoos.SelectMany(x=>x.Animals)
```

but it says

> The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany 
>   (IEnumerable, Func>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I simply just want to get all the children entities in a collection, I am trying to do this without a loop and just use LINQ to get what I want.

```
public partial class Zoo
{      
    ...
    public virtual Animal Aminals{ get; set; }
    ...
}
public partial class Animal{..}
```

These objects are EF generated, and has a relationship in the db that a zoo can have many animals.

Comment: What's the type of `Animals` property?

Comment: Animals is a EF collection that is retrieved using the .Include property on the Zoo object

Comment: Can you show the `Zoo` class?

Comment: Could you, please, provide `zoos` and `x.Animals` type definitions?

Comment: By your edit animals is of type Animal not an IEnumerable...maybe you have a list of animals inside your Animal class?

Comment: edited it.. but not sure what value that will add as they are just EF generated objects. I have generated these objects from an existing database using the Code First extract of existing database

Comment: Why is it `Animal Aminals` should't it be `List<Animal> Aminals`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectMany` is used to make collections flatten. You should use `Select`, because `Animals` property is not a collection

Comment: He wants to get animals of all zoos, so he should know this point.

Comment: His model defition says, that every `Zoo` has only one `Animal`. So he will get animals of all zoos, using `Select`

Comment: Btw, this model seems strange to me